# Check machine specifications Novell

Tags: command-line-interface, novell

what command do I use to check machine specification running novell server using the command line tool or GUI?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Novell Remote Manager, or NoRM, for this. Open this in your Internet browser: https://address_of_your_NetWare_server:8009/ . It provides lots of information about the server, including its hardware specifications.

In addition, it seems you can access data, provided by NoRM, from the command line, using Novell Remote Manager Command-Line Interface: http://www.novell.com/communities/node/11283/novell-remote-manager-command-line-interface.

Answer (score 2):

NetWare, type SPEED for CPU, type MEMORY, for memory. If it's an HP server, and insight manager is installed you can get a lot more information @ http://serverip:2301

As suggested above NORM will provide you some information too.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see, you are not clear by Novell server if you mean Netware, OES Linux, or a particular SUSE variant.

For Netware, there is SPEED to see the CPU speed.

For SUSE (and OES since it is a set of services running on top of SUSE) there is `lspci` I suppose.